Creating router app without without API or reverse engineering IP address router UI as API
I'm building a router management application for a Huawei router, but it doesn't appear to have an official API.  Are there any alternative approaches I can take to develop this application?
Features: password change, blacklisting etc
I've tried reverse engineering the API but I am struggling with the process.
